# Limit the number of rows after group

Tags: sql-server, database

I don't have deep knowledge in database queries. For example I have a table like this.

```
id | timestamp | lat   | lon
------------------------------
1  | 2016-04-06|-27.438|153.076
1  | 2016-04-03|-27.346|152.456
1  | 2016-04-04|-23.678|155.789
2  | 2016-04-04|-27.438|178.076
3  | 2016-04-04|-26.438|167.076
2  | 2016-04-05|-24.438|123.076
```

I used:

```
SELECT * FROM table order by [Timestamp]DESC
```

It returns all data by `DESC` order. But I need to get the max `timestamp` row for each `id` from mssql query. For example:

```
id | timestamp | lat   | lon
--------------------------------
1  | 2016-04-06|-27.438|153.076
2  | 2016-04-05|-24.438|123.076
3  | 2016-04-04|-26.438|167.076
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT
    id, timestamp, lat, lon
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp DESC)
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you. :-)

Answer (score 2):

use `row_number()` to get the latest timestamp by id

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, R = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp DESC)
    FROM   yourtable
) D
WHERE R = 1
```